# create procedure fails?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

when trying to create a simple procedure in mysql 5.1.47-community it fails everytime i've tried everything!
even simple things like this!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE two ()
begin
SELECT 1+1;
end;
//
```

The error is

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mydb' at line 1

Comment: Fails with what error message?

Comment: I don't see "mydb" in your query? Are you quoting the full SQL statement?

Comment: @Pekka i omitted the 'use mydb;' line as it obviously isnt the error

Comment: When omitting lines, amend the error output for the actual example accordingly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you've given doesn't correspond to the code you've pasted. You're referring to "mydb" somewhere in the SQL you're running yet it's not anywhere in the code you've put in the question.

The code you've given should work fine as I see no syntax errors, you may just need to give it a database to work on ("`test`" in my case here, perhaps it should be "`mydb`" for you?).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test.two ()
begin
    SELECT 1+1;
end;
//

DELIMITER ;

CALL test.two;
```

However, I suspect the error you're getting is become of a line in your SQL that you're not showing us.

**EDIT**
It could perhaps be the `delimiter` command. You're changing the delimiter to `//` rather than the default `;`. So perhaps you've run that command (and changed the delimiter for your session to //), and then tried to run `USE mydb;` where the `;` is no longer recognised as a valid delimiter for your session, and that could be giving you the error. Try putting `delimiter ;` before your use line and see if that helps (and then use it again after you've defined your stored procedure so you can call it). This is just a theory though, as I'm not sure of the intricacies of the delimiter command.

Comment: sorry the first line is 'use mydb;' i omitted it as its obviously not the error. strangely i have just executed 'rollback' and then your code with the db change and it succeeded?

Comment: @Mark I've updated with a new idea. This could explain why rollback caused it to work, as maybe that resets the delimiter. But as I've said in the edit, this is just a theory, I'm not in an environment where I can currently test this out to see.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final delimiter "end" instead "end;"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using [heidisql](https://www.heidisql.com/) as the fronted to enter the SQL. My first attempt was:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Add_Two (IN someNumber int, OUT result INT)
   BEGIN
     SELECT someNumber +2 INTO result;
   END
```

and this resulted in `SQL ERROR (1064)`  because i was not aware that when using a client program a [delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql) is needed to [define the stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

After changing the above to this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Add_Two(IN someNumber int, OUT result INT)
   BEGIN
     SELECT someNumber +2 INTO result;
   END
//
```

It worked out.

Example to call it

```
 SET @someNumber :=8;
 CALL Add_Two(@someNumber, @result);
 SELECT @result;
```