# MySql Trigger After Update does not update even when all is correct

Tags: mysql, triggers

**Tab_1**

```
"id"    "name"      "addr"  "country"   "status"
"1"     "norman"    "1st"   "US"        "2"
"2"     "kirk"      "2nd"   "US"        "2"
```

**Tab_2**

```
"id"    "name"      "addr"  "country"   "pos"   "total"
"1"     "norman"    "1st"   "US"        "0"     "0"
"2"     "kirk"      "2nd"   "US"        "0"     "0"
```

I'm using the below trigger after `update` on `Tab_1` to `update` `Tab_2` when the status in `Tab_1` is set to `0`. Problem is, It'll do nothing even when It's correct. How do I set this right?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tab_2_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `tab_1` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
if new.status = '0' then
update tab_2 set pos = pos+1, total = total+1 where id = new.id;
//Should it be new.id or old.id? I tried both but still no luck.
end if;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another case of multiple statements being broken because you haven't changed the delimiter. It's a pretty common error.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `tab_2_upd`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tab_2_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `tab_1` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if new.status = '0' then
        update tab_2 set pos = pos+1, total = total+1 where id = new.id;
    end if;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

ON UPDATE triggers have both OLD and NEW values, and since I don't think that value of `id` is ever going to change (it shouldn't) it is safe to use any value (OLD or NEW).

There's a nice answer on delimiters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql).