# Custom Functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simple custom function in MySQL that takes 2 values (id int, currencyValue double), looks up a value in another table based on the id and returns the currencyValue*rate.

Here is my psuedo-code that is not getting me anywhere near this. There is also a surprising lack of examples of this on Google.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ConvertCurrency
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_ConvertCurrency //
CREATE FUNCTION F_ConvertCurrency(PID INT, C_VALUE DOUBLE) 
RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN

  DECLARE Currency_Rate DOUBLE;

  SET Currency_Rate = SELECT `Rate` FROM `Currencies` WHERE `ID` = PID;
  RETURN Currency_Rate*C_VALUE;
END;//
```

I am getting the 'there is an error in your code near...' which helps me none.
I have seen other examples of functions with the DELMITER keyword but have no idea what this means.

Comment: What MySQL client are you using to create this? The `DELIMITER` keyword is specific to the command-line MySQL client.  You should have a `//` delimiter after your first `DROP FUNCTION`, and it looks like you should remove the `;` after the final `END`. That should be the delimiter `//`

Comment: See also [Delimiters in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/10259528#10259528)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `DELIMITER` to something other than a semi-colon (I use `$$`) temporarily in order to use semi-colons in the body of your stored function definition.

You can use `SELECT ... INTO ...` in order to set the local Currency_Rate variable. I recommend prefixing the variable name with `v_` as well to represent the fact that it is a local variable as opposed to a table column.

Here's an example using your code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ConvertCurrency $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_ConvertCurrency $$
CREATE FUNCTION F_ConvertCurrency(PID INT, C_VALUE DOUBLE) 
RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_Currency_Rate DOUBLE;

  SELECT `Rate` 
  INTO v_Currency_Rate
  FROM `Currencies` 
  WHERE `ID` = PID;

  RETURN v_Currency_Rate*C_VALUE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are creating a function, you are using many times the standard instruction terminator `;`, so you must tell MySQL to ignore it until you are done.

So, you need to write your procedure like this:

```
delimiter $$
drop function if exists F_ConvertCurrency $$
create function F_ConvertCurrency(PID INT, C_VALUE DOUBLE) returns DOUBLE
BEGIN
    declare Currency_Rate DOUBLE;
    set Currency_Rate = (SELECT `Rate` from `Currencies` WHERE `ID`=PID);
    return Currency_Rate * C_VALUE;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Things to remember:

- When you want to assign a variable with a `select` query, enclose the query in parenthesis. One alternative is to use `select column into variable from yourTable where...`.
- At the end of the procedure (or function) declaration, don't use `;` but use the custom delimiter you defined earlier.
- **Always** remember to restore the default delimiter (by using: `delimiter ;`)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the code works fine. I chose to select Ike's answer as correct because his came in first.