# Stored procedure in Mysql version 5.6.11

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create stored Procedure using Mysql version 5.6.11 but it showing some error,
here is my Code.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Debug(Message TEXT)
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _debug (
        id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        msg TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
     );
 INSERT INTO _debug(`msg`) VALUES(Message);
 END;
```

I am getting this error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8`

Comment: What client are you using to create it? For some (notably the mysql command line client) you must set the `DELIMITER`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql

Comment: The fact that you used `;` after `END` suggests the delimiter is not being handled correctly...

Comment: I am using php myadmin. and belowed answer giving this error '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delmiter $$ CREATE PROCEDURE Debug(Message TEXT) BEGIN CREATE TABLE I' at line 1'

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has its own different method of setting the delimiter. The command `DELIMITER` is specific to the mysql CLI client. There should be an input field in PHPMyAdmin to set a custom delimiter like `$$`.  Set that field and end the procedure with `END$$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ;

```
delmiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Debug(Message TEXT)
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _debug (
        id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        msg TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (id))
 INSERT INTO _debug(`msg`) VALUES(Message)
 END$$
```