# MySQL syntax error in WHILE statement

Tags: mysql

I'm working through learning MySQL (v 5.6) and trying to get a simple `WHILE` loop to go through. I even just straight copy & paste from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html) (with added `SELECT v1;` statement).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SELECT v1;
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Workbench is giving me this error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() BEGIN   DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT
>   5 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3   0.001 sec

Any insight from more experienced MySQL programmers is very appreciated!

Comment: What MySQL client are you using? (edit - I see it's Workbench) If you are using the command line client, you'll need to set the `DELIMITER`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql. Other clients (like PHPMyAdmin) have their own methods of setting an alternate delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure looks ok I guess you are missing the delimiter

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
  BEGIN
   DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;
    WHILE v1 > 0 DO
     SET v1 = v1 - 1;
   END WHILE;
 END; //
delimiter ;
```