# Insert 13000 rows in existing table

Tags: mysql, loops, insert

I am trying to insert 13k rows in my table.
My table structure is as follow

ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |

ID is the primary (auto-increment) column.

I need Col1 to reflect number 1 to 13000.

The rest of the columns will remain blank.

I am sure this question has been asked before but I am really confused as to how to do that efficiently.
Thanks

Comment: there is no "efficient" way: do 13,000 inserts. either the mysql extended syntax, or 13,000 separate inserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://naspinski.net/post/Running-a-For-Loop-in-MS-SQL.aspx

Follow the example posted here. your `While (@count < 40)` will be 13000, `Set @count = 0` will be 1, and instead of `insert into some_table ([columnA], [column]) Values ('val1', 'val2')` it will just have `[columnA]` and `@count` instead of `val1`. The modified example below should suffice.

SQL Command:

```
DECLARE @count INT   
SET @count = 1   
WHILE (@count < 13001)   

BEGIN   
  INSERT INTO some_table ([Col1]) VALUES (@count)   
  SET @count = (@count + 1)   
END
```

MYSQL Command:

```
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @count INT;  
  SET @count = 1;  

  WHILE (@count < 13001)
    INSERT INTO 'some_table' ('col1') VALUES (@count);  
    SET @count = (@count + 1);  
  END WHILE;  
END;
```

Comment: I think this is my best option. However, how do I include this in a php script? Or is this a direct SQL command?

Comment: this is a SQL command/query that would get executed against the database.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run the query in the SQL command:

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @count INT
SET count = 1
WHILE (count < 5)

BEGIN
   INSERT I' at line 1

Comment: Are you trying to execute this from PHP? If so, what exactly is the code you are running it at? It seems you are running into a quotation/parsing issue.

Comment: I am running it from the SQL command on phpmyadmin. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After researching online, it seems that this error has to do with delimiters but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The MySQL code should correct that problem based on readings here <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html> as well as <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598218/mysql-syntax-error-in-while-statement>.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of loading data into MySQL is to load it from a local delimited file.  MySQL has a [load local infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command that does this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (Col1);
```

Where your input file is just a list of the Col1 values, one per line:

```
8377
3888
3244
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your source of the information.

Each platform has it's own ways of doing this.

Microsoft has their integration services for example. But if it is simple data then you could create a regex replace to encapsulate the data into a number of select queries that inserts into the table.

But I need to know more about which database and the source of the information to help you anymore.

Comment: I am using mysql for the database.

Comment: Maybe im making to much of assumptions, but my guess is that the data (13k) is not already in the database in other tables? Is so what is your source of the data. A excel file?

Comment: No, the data needs to be created at the same time. Thanks