# MySQL 5.7 Cannot find error in simple WHILE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use a `WHILE` loop in MySQL v5.7 and keep getting a syntax error. I haven't been able to identify the problem. The syntax looks correct according to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html).

I found a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598218/mysql-syntax-error-in-while-statement) suggesting wrapping the statement in a DELIMITER, but this did not work either. The code is:

```
SET @counter = 1;

WHILE (@counter < 2) DO
    SELECT @counter;
    @counter = @counter + 1;
END WHILE
```

and the error message is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 22: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'WHILE (@counter < 2) DO
>       SELECT @counter' at line 1

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you use the DELIMITER show us.

Comment: Yes, I tried with and without a semi-colon after the `END WHILE`. When using the delimiter, I put `DELIMITER //` before the above block and `//` after (with and without the semi-colon).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember, you cannot use WHILE LOOP just like that. You have to put it inside a Stored Procedure like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE counter < 2 DO
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Don't forget `DELIMITER`

Comment: This is the closest so far. The above code, with the DELIMITER, gives me a different error: ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 18: Access denied for user 'run_OT1FwXgLf31'@'localhost' to database 'run_ot1fwxglf31' Looks like I can't create a procedure in this environment :-(

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code. It ran successfully on my MySQL 5.7

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE mysp()
BEGIN
   DECLARE counter INT;
   SET counter = 1;

   label1: WHILE counter < 2 DO
     SELECT counter;
     SET counter = counter + 1;
   END WHILE label1;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your sample procedure is exemplary. Two thing I found missing in my simple procedure after reading your script:
1) The ; after last END, event with different DELIMITER declared.
2) The label `label1` for the `while` loop
However I can safely remove the label if I don't want to and I can still successfully create my procedure. Many thanks!!!