# What does `\g` mean at the end of a MySQL statement? And how do I fix queries not running?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

I have an auto-generated SQL script to run on 5.6.17-157.2.

It worked fine on 5.5.33-1.17.1.

Every SQL statement shows `\g` at the end. For example

```
CREATE TABLE articoli
(
ID                                                                INT,
titolo                                                            LONGTEXT,
sottotitolo                                                       LONGTEXT,
descrizione                                                       LONGTEXT,
note                                                              LONGTEXT,
nomeopzione1                                                      LONGTEXT,
nomeopzione2                                                      LONGTEXT,
nomeopzione3                                                      LONGTEXT,
pagina                                                            CHAR(100),
sottopagina                                                       SMALLINT,
plain_titolo                                                      CHAR(200),
plain_sottotitolo                                                 CHAR(200),
nomeopzione4                                                      LONGTEXT,
KEY (ID),
KEY (pagina),
KEY (sottopagina)
);\g
```

What changed between the two version to break query execution? How can I tell 5.6 to accept \g and don't care?

I can't just change the SQL. It's auto-generated code that must run as final step of a monstrous software abomination "daily update" (https://serverfault.com/questions/458340/euro-character-messed-up-during-ftp-transfer)

[Update] Better change the question: it's not enough to know what is that. I need to get the queries running.

Comment: Upvoted both. I was dumb enough to phrase the question wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL already does accept `\g`, but it must follow a SQL statement.

The `\g` is basically the same as `;` That is, it is the terminator for a statement and that means send it to the server for parsing and execution.

Your sample shows a create table statement terminated by *both* a semicolon and `\g`. This results in the create table statement running, because it has a semicolon. But then it tries to run another statement terminator without a statement.

Try this:

```
mysql> ;
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Of course there was no query specified, this just shows a semicolon with no query.

It's the same with a line with nothing but `\g`:

```
mysql> \g
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

And if you run a real query, and then a redundant terminator of either type, you get something similar. It runs the first query, then fails on the empty query:

```
mysql> select 123; ;
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql> select 123; \g
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

I don't know what you mean about this code is generated and you can't change it. You'll have to, because what you've got won't work.

I would suggest you strip out the `\g` from your file before trying to run it. Here's an example of a file containing the bad empty-query pattern, and using sed to remove the redundant `\g`:

```
$ cat > bad.sql
select 123; \g

$ sed -e 's/\\g//g' bad.sql
select 123;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html

> go -  (\g) - Send command to mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

(\g) -> go 
Send command to mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

`\g`(`go`) has the same function as `;`(default delimiter) to run a SQL statement in MySQL. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479768/ego-or-go-doesnt-work-after-a-sql-statement-in-mysql/77479769#77479769) explains how to use `\g`(`go`) and `\G`(`ego`) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter more:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person\g  
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```

In addition, to run a SQL statement, `\g` is also used in PostgreSQL according to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-G) and `GO`(`go`) is used in Microsoft SQL Server(MSSQL) according to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16).