# `ego` or `go` doesn't work after a SQL statement in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

First of all, [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) says below:

```
mysql> help
...
ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
...
go        (\g) Send command to mysql server.
...
```

But, [ego](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) or [go](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648955264) doesn't work after a SQL statement as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> ego
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> go
```

While [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) or [\g](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648955264) works after a SQL statement as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
name: John
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  id: 2
name: David
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> \g
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```

So, how can I make `ego` or `go` work after a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [--named-commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_named-commands) or [-G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_named-commands) with login to make [ego](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) or [go](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648955264) work after a SQL statement as shown below:

```
mysql -u john -p --named-commands
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p -G
```

Or on Windows, you can set `named-commands` under `[mysql]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[mysql]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[mysql]
...
named-commands
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` to make `ego` or `go` work after a SQL statement as shown below. *`--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` must be the 1st option otherwise there is [the error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600):

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p
```

Finally, `ego` or `go` works after a SQL statement as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> ego
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
name: John
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  id: 2
name: David
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person
    -> go
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```

In addition, `ego` or `go` doesn't work just after a SQL statement as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM personego
    ->
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person ego
    ->
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM persongo
    ->
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person go
    ->
```

While [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) or [\g](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648955264) works just after a SQL statement as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person\G  
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
name: John
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  id: 2
name: David
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person \G  
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
name: John
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  id: 2
name: David
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person\g  
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person \g  
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```