# Error in case in mysql for creating procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
create procedure temp (in empId int)
begin
 declare emptype varchar;
    select emptype = qoute(emptype) from dms_document where id =  empid;
    select emptype

 case  
when emptype = 'P' then
    select doctype from dms_report where pilot = 1
else
select 'No Documents required'
end case
end;
```

This is my query i am creating procedure in MySQL,  i am getting error in case statement please hlep me  why this error is coming how declare case statement why error is coming in workbench for creating procdure

Comment: What error? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i am getting Error in Select and case key word when trying to create procdure.

Comment: Pro SO tip - when you're asking a question, you should always put the actual error messages in the question. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I formatted your procedure Use [delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp ( empId INT)
    BEGIN
     DECLARE var_etype VARCHAR(36);

SELECT 
    emptype = QOUTE(emptype)
FROM
    dms_document
WHERE
    id = empid;
SELECT 
    emptype,
    CASE
        WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype
        ELSE 'No Documents required'
    END
FROM
    dms_report
WHERE
    pilot = 1;
End//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missed comma.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE temp (IN empId INT)
        BEGIN
         DECLARE emptype VARCHAR;
            SELECT emptype = qoute(emptype) FROM dms_document WHERE id =  empid;
                SELECT emptype,

     CASE  
    WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype;

    ELSE 'No Documents required';
    END CASE ;
    FROM dms_report WHERE pilot = 1
End;
```

Comment: now error coming in select keyword  SELECT doctype FROM dms_report WHERE pilot = 1  in this line

Comment: any solution why this Error coming  in select key word

Comment: It's executing or not?

Comment: No now again Error on Syntax of ELSE END CASE SYNTAX ERROR i dont know why this Error coming

Comment: NO  i am trying to run it in Venkatesh Panabaka mysql workbench i dont know why this error coming

Comment: please tell me how to fix it .