# MYSQL trigger error (lots of function)

Tags: mysql, database, function, triggers, declare

i can't seem to found any fault on my code to make a trigger. ( i usually code using oracle, but i convert to my sql in this project, checked all the function and convert those that aren't available in mysql already)

here's the code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `transaction_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `transaction` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(12);
   DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5);
   TEMP:= CONCAT('T',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'));
   SELECT CONCAT(TEMP, LPAD(NVL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,5,5) AS UNSIGNED))+1,1),5,0)) 
   FROM TRANSACTION INTO TEMPKODE
   WHERE SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,1,4) = TEMP;
   NEW.TRANSACTION_ID := TEMPKODE;
 END
```

**EDIT 1:**

i'm coding it from heidisql if there's any code difference, since i heard if i do it on mysql work bench i should use 
SET variables 
instead of directly 
variables :=

the desired result is forex: T201600001 
//T for transaction, 2016 i got it from dateformat, and the rest is choosing the biggest data from the database 
it's a software for production planning so i'm making the transaction code

Comment: Show us the whole trigger declaration, please. You may have messed up the tricky MySQL `SET DELIMITER` hack.  Also please show the error you're getting.

Comment: oh sorry, since i think the whole trigger is only create or replace trigger etc

Comment: here's the whole code                                                                   CREATE TRIGGER `transaction_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `transaction` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(12);
 DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5);
 TEMP:= CONCAT('T',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'));
 SELECT CONCAT(TEMP, LPAD(NVL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,5,5) AS UNSIGNED))+1,1),5,0)) 
 FROM TRANSACTION INTO TEMPKODE
 WHERE SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,1,4) = TEMP;
 NEW.TRANSACTION_ID := TEMPKODE;
END @ollie-jones

Comment: what is set delimiter anyway? sorry i found it [Delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  There may be easier ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NVL`, is a function built for you?, Oracle `NVL` function does not exist in MySQL (find its equivalent in MySQL), see [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```sql
DELIMITER $$

BEGIN
    DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(12);
    DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT CONCAT('T',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'));
    -- OR: SET TEMP := CONCAT('T',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'));
    -- TEMP := CONCAT('T',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'));

    /*
    SELECT CONCAT(TEMP,LPAD(NVL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,5,5) AS UNSIGNED))+1,1),5,0))
    FROM TRANSACTION INTO TEMPKODE
    WHERE SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,1,4) = TEMP;
    */

    SELECT CONCAT(TEMP,LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,5,5) AS UNSIGNED))+1,1),5,0))
    FROM TRANSACTION
    WHERE SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,1,4) = TEMP INTO TEMPKODE;

    -- NEW.TRANSACTION_ID := TEMPKODE;
    SET NEW.TRANSACTION_ID := TEMPKODE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

You can simplify with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899582/1316440) of @GordonLinoff:

```sql
SET NEW.TRANSACTION_ID := CONCAT(...);
```

Comment: so i need to change my nvl into ifnull right? at do i need to add DELIMITER command? @wchiquito

Comment: @RobertWilliam: Evaluate [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) and determine if it does what you need. `DELIMITER` is used when creating the trigger.

Comment: i still got the error but it is near the bottom line oh and i remove delimeter since it isn't supported at heidi, it's on this line    WHERE SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID,1,4) = TEMP; it is said that an error occured near that line @wchiquito

Comment: it worked ! thanks a lot, just the into tempkode must be put before //from what table, it won't work if you put the into tempkode AFTER from transaction. thanks for the help! @wchiquito

Comment: @RobertWilliam: You can place `INTO` after `WHERE` too, see [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Comment: oh okay, i don't know why when i put the INTO after WHERE it gives me an error. thanks anyway @wchiquito

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need temporary variables for this operation (in either Oracle or MySQL).  I think the following is the same logic:

```
BEGIN
    select new.transactionid := CONCAT('T', YEAR(now()),
                                       LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_ID, 5, 5) + 1
                                                        ), 1
                                                    ), 5, 0)
    from transaction t
    where TRANSACTION_ID LIKE CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '%')
END;
```

Comment: wow that's very efficient, i don't need to cast the substr transaction_id as integer though? since it's saved as varchar @GordonLinoff

Comment: anyway you got an error on your code @GordonLinoff "you have an error in your SQL Syntax check the manual that corresponds your MySql server version to use the right syntax near ':= CONCAT('T',YEAR(NOW()) BLABLABLA at line 2 "