# database Why the database cannot recognize timestamp when creating event

Tags: mysql

I want to create an event to reset field starting from 2016-02-23 00:00:00

```
CREATE EVENT reset_count
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 72 HOUR STARTS '2016-02-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO BEGIN
UPDATE table_1 SET count1 = 0;
```

And then, the following error appears:
you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7.

It seems that the database cannot recognize the '2016-02-23 00:00:00'. Why?

Comment: The `syntax to use near ''` points to an error at the end of the statement. It looks like it is only missing the `END` keyword to go with the `BEGIN` you have.

Comment: But the `BEGIN/END` are probably not needed in this case because you only execute one `UPDATE` statement in this event. They would be needed to group multiple statements.

Comment: When I typed UPDATE table_1 SET count1 = 0; and then press "enter", the error came immediately without allowing press any words anymore.

Comment: So, END may not be needed.

Comment: Hello do you use phpmyadmin or not ? i have been in this issue too, i will give trick if you use phpmyadmin

Comment: I haven't as I use the server from my university.

Comment: Are you using the MySQL command line client? You likely need a delimiter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `BEGIN` without `END` and may be a delimiter issue too.

Try the following :

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `reset_count`;
CREATE EVENT `reset_count`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 72 HOUR STARTS '2016-02-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
UPDATE table_1 SET count1 = 0;
```

If a delimiter issue arises:

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT `reset_count`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 72 HOUR STARTS '2016-02-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
UPDATE table_1 SET count1 = 0;
//
```

**EDIT:**

**Note:**

- Check whether `event scheduler` is `on`.

  `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`
- If the `event scheduler` is `OFF` then you need to set
  `event_scheduler` `ON`.

  `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

**More:**

> BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which
>   can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions,
>   triggers, and events). A compound statement can contain multiple
>   statements, enclosed by the BEGIN and END keywords.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html)

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you @Keroro Chan

Comment: The first one works. But, when do I need "BEGIN/END"?

Comment: Usually `BEGIN` `END`  is used in stored programs. You must use `BEGIN` ....`END` if you write compound statements. For single statement it is optional. But you cannot use `BEGIN` without `END`. @KeroroChan

Comment: I got it. Can you give an example what are compound statements?

Comment: Suppose you have another event the purposes of which are to insert some value into `table_1` and to update some rows in `table_2`. Then these two statements (`insert `and `update`) would be considered `compound statements`.

Comment: I tested the first code you provided. The system does not reset the field, but the event is there. How come?

Comment: the field will be reset when the event is scheduled. Look the event is scheduled in every 72 hours interval starting from '2016-02-23 00:00:00'. Since the start date is already a past date so the next schedule is 2016-02-26 00:00:00.