# Create an 'if' trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a trigger that will only run if the condition is met.

```
create trigger t_free 
before insert on vacation_days
for each row 
if new.days_newtier>= 365 
then set new.free=new.days_CurrYear*(select a.rate 
from algorithm a where new.work_days between a.day1 and a.day2);
```

I keep getting a syntax error. The trigger works fine without the if statement.

Comment: You need a `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN...END`. Look over some user-contributed examples in the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: It looks like you also missed a compulsory `END IF` if this is MySQL. Please specify MySQL or SQLite as the syntax differs.

Comment: Even after putting a "begin, end if, and end" it keeps stating that I am missing a semicolon after "a.day2" when if fact it is present. Is there something else that I am missing in the statement, like a declare "old as new". @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: This is MySQL then? What client are you using to create the trigger? The MySQL command line client and Workbench would require you to use a `DELIMITER` to set an alternate delimiter. Other clients have their own methods of specifying it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql