# mySQL TRIGGER error code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
USE test;
CREATE TRIGGER AvgUpdateTrigger AFTER INSERT ON test.score
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test.average (test.average.TestID, test.average.TestAvg)
(SELECT test.score.TestID, avg(test.score.ScoreValue) FROM test.score GROUP BY test.score.TestID)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE test.average.TestAvg = (SELECT avg(test.score.ScoreValue) FROM test.score WHERE test.score.TestID = test.average.TestID GROUP BY test.score.TestID);
END;
```

im trying to update one table(average) when another one gets changed(score)
it is telling me to add a semicolon but as you can see there is one there allready

Comment: What MySQL client are you using to execute this? It's possible you you need to specify an alternate `DELIMITER`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql

Comment: mySQL workbench

Comment: For Workbench, you probably do need to set `DELIMITER`. Follow the examples in the linked question.

Comment: For one-statement-triggers the delimiter doesn't need to be changed. Just remove the semicolon after your insert statement. And also remove BEGIN and END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a trigger (or any stored procedure) contains only one statement, you don't need `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AvgUpdateTrigger AFTER INSERT ON test.score
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO test.average (TestID, TestAvg)
        SELECT test.score.TestID, avg(test.score.ScoreValue)
        FROM test.score
        GROUP BY test.score.TestID
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            test.average.TestAvg = VALUES(TestAvg);
```

I also replaced the subquery with `VALUES(TestAvg)`, since this value has already been selected.