# MySQL query: multi level category on the same table

Tags: mysql

Good day earthlings,

This is my table structure

```
acctCode| refAcctCode | acctName
------    ----------    --------
 AC001                    SALES
 AC002                    AR
 AC003     AC001          FURNITURE
 AC004     AC003          OFFICE FURNITURE
 AC005     AC002          INVOICE
 AC006     AC001          UTILITIES
```

and expected output would be

```
SALES
    FURNITURE
        OFFICE FURNITURE
    UTILITIES
AR
    INVOICE
```

however it its not only limited on level 3 alone but to the nth

eg:

```
Parent1
  Child1
    child1.1
      child1.1.1
        child1.1.1.1
  child2
  child3
  child3

parent2
  child1
  child2
  child3
```

Given the table structure format, how do I query to get that output?

thanks

Comment: Please add formatting to your question

Comment: Sorry sir but my current connection is not stable ATM. Page load longer than it was expected.

Comment: MySQL doesn't presently have native support for recursion. Options include joining the table to itself as often as could be required, writing a sproc, handling the recursion logic in application code, or switching to an alternativemodel, e.g. nested sets. All of these options have been widely discussed.

Comment: I see, can you provide me an example, or it is possible to limit in level 3, I am new to query and start to learning myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on a user defined procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE list()
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp; -- for collecting the records
 CREATE TABLE tmp (id varchar(1024), name varchar(128));
 SET @i=-5; SET @s=0;      -- @i: offset for id comparison
                           -- @s: space padding for name column
 INSERT INTO tmp           -- fill in entries without refAcctCode
 SELECT a.acctCode, a.acctName FROM tbl a WHERE a.refAcctCode is null;

                           -- do as often as necessary ...    
 WHILE ROW_COUNT() > 0 DO 
  SET @i=@i+6; SET @s=@s+2;-- increment variables
  INSERT INTO tmp
  SELECT CONCAT(id,' ',a.acctCode), CONCAT(SPACE(@s),a.acctName) 
  FROM tbl a INNER JOIN tmp b ON SUBSTR(id,@i)=a.refAcctCode;
 END WHILE;

 SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY id;  -- list the consolidated temp. table
END;
```

By executing it with

```
CALL list()
```

You get the following output:

```
    id                name
------------------------------------------
1   AC001             SALES
2   AC001 AC003         FURNITURE
3   AC001 AC003 AC004     OFFICE FURNITURE
4   AC001 AC006         UTILITIES
5   AC002             AR
6   AC002 AC005         INVOICE
```

You can find a working Demo here: http://rextester.com/ZRXN57872

I used spaces to prefix the `accName` column. This makes it easier to see the category levels in the results listing. Feel free to play around with the procedure to make it fit your particular needs.

Comment: splendid sir. however when I paste code on mysql. I got errors on while statement.

Comment: Can you provide us with the actual messages? Sometimes with MySQL there can be issues with delimiters, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql