# MySQL: Query weird behaviour - need new row before FROM to succeed

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with really weird situation. I am generating code from my php editor, and as you know I am getting code non-formatted all in one line.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT ua.id            AS ua_id, 
       ua.activity_time AS ua_activity_time, 
       ua.user_id       AS ua_user_id, 
       ua.charter_id    AS ua_charter_id, 
       'table'          AS ua_table_name, 
       Concat(Round(Timestampdiff(minute, ua.activity_time, Now()) / 30, 0), '-' 
       , ua.charter_id)   AS delimiter 
FROM   user_activity_charter_update AS ua 
WHERE  ua.activity_time BETWEEN '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-10 00:00:00'
```

It reports syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_activity_charter_update AS ua WHERE ua.activity_time BETWEEN '2018-07-10 00' at line 1

But what is more weird when I hit space before **FROM** and put it in new row, query works fine.

[image: Error example]
[image: Working example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in keyword **delimter** in SELECT statement, because mysql interprets **delimiter** in your query as command. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql) more about delimiters. So, if you change keyword **delimiter** to something else, that is not keyword, it will work fine. :)

Working example:

```
SELECT ua.id            AS ua_id, 
       ua.activity_time AS ua_activity_time, 
       ua.user_id       AS ua_user_id, 
       ua.charter_id    AS ua_charter_id, 
       'table'          AS ua_table_name, 
       Concat(Round(Timestampdiff(minute, ua.activity_time, Now()) / 30, 0), '-' , ua.charter_id)   AS test_delimiter 
FROM   user_activity_charter_update AS ua 
WHERE  ua.activity_time BETWEEN '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-10 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Amazing response. It definitely solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In first picture you have selected just part of a query, so when you try tu execute the query, **you actually trying to execute just selected part**. That's the reason of the error.

Comment: You sir have eagle eyes.

Comment: Sorry but actually not, It selects part where error occurs. I have selected whole query and executed, but still it fails.

Comment: @Lululu Try putting `WHERE` clause in one line and give it a run.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I have just tried it but still nothing, it only works with `FROM` in new line.