# Unable to create stored procedures in Mysql 5.6.13

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, rds

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure in MYSQL 5.6.13

```
create procedure create_logger_id(IN mobile BIGINT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mobile FROM USER_REG_TYPE;
END
```

But Get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

I even tried `delimiter //`, `DECLARE mobile INT` and few others all of them lead to the same error.

The MYSQL server is hosted on AWS RDS (Added this info to understand if there is a known issue)

Update:
if I try

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE create_logger_id(IN mobile BIGINT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mobile FROM USER_REG_TYPE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I even tried delimiter //"? You need the delimiter. Add it to your question, you may have used it incorrectly.

Comment: Shouldn't that parameter be declared as OUT mobile BIGINT if you want to get the COUNT() of USER_REG_TYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a delimiter.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE create_logger_id(IN mobile BIGINT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mobile FROM USER_REG_TYPE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'd like to encourage you to read more on delimiters: [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1` this is the error it throws

Comment: @NikhilVarma `DELIMITER` is not a MySQL command. It's a command that your MySQL client needs to support. Which client are you using?

Comment: @NikhilVarma Which version?

Comment: @IIdar Build 112, Please note its [Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) and Not mysql workbench. I also use SQLYog. You can provide a resolution in either of these. Update :DELIMITER// is SQLYog worked

Comment: @NikhilVarma Sounds like it's a problem with Workbench/J. Just looked at their docs, and their MySQL connector is somewhat weird.