# Mysql delimiter syntax error only get error on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have create procedure code. When I try run create procedure codes in phpmyadmin, it is works. But when I try run in c#, it is return error like that:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER !!

Create Procedure Code:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_alldoctorname`(IN `p_doktor` VARCHAR(65) CHARSET latin5, IN `p_eski` VARCHAR(65) CHARSET latin5)
    NO SQL
    BEGIN
UPDATE users SET hekim=p_doktor WHERE hekim=p_eski;
UPDATE tedavi SET tedavi_doktor=p_doktor WHERE tedavi_doktor=p_eski;
UPDATE medikal SET doktor=p_doktor WHERE doktor=p_eski;
UPDATE cek_devreden SET unvan=p_doktor WHERE unvan=p_eski;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `DELIMITER ;;` syntax with `MySqlCommand` in C#. Instead, just use the body of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement as the `MySqlCommand.CommandText` and execute it:

```
using (var command = yourConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_alldoctorname`(IN `p_doktor` VARCHAR(65) CHARSET latin5, IN `p_eski` VARCHAR(65) CHARSET latin5)
    NO SQL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET hekim=p_doktor WHERE hekim=p_eski;
        UPDATE tedavi SET tedavi_doktor=p_doktor WHERE tedavi_doktor=p_eski;
        UPDATE medikal SET doktor=p_doktor WHERE doktor=p_eski;
        UPDATE cek_devreden SET unvan=p_doktor WHERE unvan=p_eski;
    END";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```