# computed column using value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table kit(id int unsigned not null auto_increment, creator int unsigned not null, name varchar(16) not null, script longtext not null, tag as concat(select username from user where id = creator, '/', name), primary key (id));
```

doesn't work because I am trying to make `tag` a computed column

I want two tables, `user` looks like

```
+----+------------------+
| id | username         |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 1234567890123456 |
+----+------------------+
```

and `kit` looks like

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| id | creator |  name  | script |           tag           |
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | kitkit | long   | 1234567890123456/kitkit |
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
```

The tag column should be auto-computed from the username of the creator and the name of the kit.

I thought my column declaration would work:

```
tag as concat(select username from user where id = creator, '/', name)
```

but I guess not.

Comment: Use a user-defined function or view.

Comment: Or maybe a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (NB! not tested)

```
create table kit(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
creator int unsigned not null, 
name varchar(16) not null, 
script longtext not null, 
tag varchar(33) not null, primary key (id));

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER contacts_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON contacts FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE vtag varchar(33);
   -- Fill tag value
   select concat(username,'/',OLD.name) from user where id = OLD.creator INTO vtag;

   -- Update created_by field to the username of the person performing the INSERT
   SET NEW.tag = vtag;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what's delimiter

Comment: From [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504] 

> Note that the DELIMITER keyword is a function of the command line mysql client (and some other clients) only and not a regular MySQL language feature. It won't work if you tried to pass it through a programming language API to MySQL.