# Stored procedure Mysql BEGIN END

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dbforge

I am writing a simple stored procedure to take data and enter it into a table

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'gunsdb-3939c99d-COPY-39393fb6'@'%'
PROCEDURE `gunsdb-3939c99d-COPY-39393fb6`.sp_entity_save(IN p_entity_id INT, IN p_entity_type_id INT, IN p_title_id INT, IN p_first_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_last_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_street_line_1 VARCHAR(255), IN p_street_line_2 VARCHAR(255), IN p_street_line_3 VARCHAR(255), IN p_town VARCHAR(255), IN p_county VARCHAR(255), IN p_postcode VARCHAR(255), IN p_email VARCHAR(255), IN p_telephone INT, IN p_company_name VARCHAR(500), IN p_company_desc VARCHAR(500), IN p_website VARCHAR(500), IN p_rfd_number INT, IN p_issuing_force VARCHAR(255), IN p_concent VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO tbl_entity (
entity_id,
entity_type_id,
title_id,
first_name,
last_name,
street_line_1,
street_line_2,
street_line_3,
town,county,
postcode,
email,
telephone,
company_name,
company_desc,
website,
rfd_number,
issuing_force,
concent
)

VALUES
(
p_entity_id,
p_entity_type_id,
p_title_id,
p_first_name,
p_last_name,
p_street_line_1 , 
p_street_line_2,
p_street_line_3 ,
p_town, @county , 
p_postcode,
p_email ,
p_telephone,
p_company_name , 
p_company_desc, 
p_website, 
p_rfd_number , 
p_issuing_force , 
p_concent
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    entity_type_id = p_entity_type_id, 
    title_id = p_title_id, 
    first_name = p_first_name, 
    last_name = p_last_name, 
    street_line_1 = p_street_line_1,
    street_line_2 = p_street_line_2,
    street_line_2 = p_street_line_2,
    town = p_town,
    county= p_county,
    postcode = p_postcode,
    email = p_email,
    telephone = p_telephone,
    company_name = p_company_name,
    company_desc = p_company_desc,
    website = p_website,
    rfd_number = p_rfd_number,
    issuing_force = p_issuing_force,
    concent = p_concent  
END
```

The above is throwing an error but as soon as a remove the BEGIN and END it is working fine and I don't understand why.

I have tried adding in DELIMITER but just seem to get the same issue:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 77 SQL1.sql 77 3

I am using dbforge but I have also tried in Navicat and getting the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: Since you only have one statement in your procedure you don't need a `BEGIN` and `END` (hence it works). However when you *do* have the `BEGIN` and `END`, you need to separate the `INSERT` statement from the `END` statement with a `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use proper delimiter? In your code there's no delimiter at the end of insert.
You should use delimiter at the end of insert.

```
delimiter //
CREATE 
PROCEDURE sp_entity_save(IN p_entity_id INT, IN p_concent VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO tbl_entity (
entity_id,
concent
)
VALUES
(
p_entity_id,
p_concent
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -- delimiter here
    concent = p_concent;
-- delimiter here
END //
```

Comment: I had to use delimiter $$ and I forgot about the ; at the end of the insert - is there any reason why it wont work with //?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with delimiter $$ or delimiter //. The link on the comment by @Jorge Campos on your question has a good explanation. read it.