# Can't make my stored procedure work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to create an stored procedure, but it always gives me an error

I've tried changing the symbols in the Delimiter, even removing the Delimiter, but nothing seems to work

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE`check_values`(IN Autoridad, IN TipoVehiculo)
BEGIN
    IF((Autoridad <> 'Transito') OR (Autoridad <> 'Fiscalia')  OR (Autoridad <> 'Pol_Car') OR (Autoridad <> 'Juzgado')) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Autoridad no valida';
    END IF;
    IF((TipoVehiculo <> 'Automovil') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Bicicleta') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Bus') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Buseta') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Camion') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Camioneta') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Ciclomotor') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Furgoneta')OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Moto') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Motocarro') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Motocultor') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Tractocamion') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Tractocarro') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Trolebus') OR (TipoVehiculo <> 'Volqueta')) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Tipo de vehiculo no valido';
    END IF;  
END;//
DELIMITER;
```

It returns an error in line 1: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'DELIMITER / / CREATE PROCEDURE `check_values`(IN Autoridad, IN TipoVehiculo) BEG' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

"DELIMITER" is a client directive rather than a command the client passes to the server. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql) indicates the error you are seeing may be caused by using a client that doesn't recognize "DELIMITER".

In addition, the next syntax error MySQL will show is that the arguments need a variable type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'check_values'(IN Autoridad VARCHAR, IN TipoVehiculo VARCHAR)
```

Finally, you may wish to review the logic in your `IF` statements. As written they will always be true and the procedure will always `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'`. For example, if Autoridad == 'Fiscalia' then the term `Autoridad <> 'Transito'` will be True which means, when combined with 'OR', as you are doing, the whole predicate is true. Typically what you seem to be attempting is coded as either

```
IF((Autoridad <> 'Transito') AND (Autoridad <> 'Fiscalia') AND (Autoridad <> 'Pol_Car') AND (Autoridad <> 'Juzgado')) THEN
```

or equally effective

```
IF NOT ((Autoridad == 'Transito') OR (Autoridad = 'Fiscalia')  OR (Autoridad == 'Pol_Car') OR (Autoridad == 'Juzgado')) THEN
```

Comment: Now is giving me a syntax error in this line: ```IF NOT ((Autoridad == 'Transito') OR (Autoridad = 'Fiscalia')  OR (Autoridad == 'Pol_Car') OR (Autoridad == 'Juzgado')) THEN```