# Problem with DECLARE variable using XAMPP / MariaDB (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a function for my MariaDB using XAMPP:

```
create definer = root@localhost 
function sunshine.get_next_gid() returns int
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_val int;
    update sunshine.gid_seq set gid = gid + 1;
    select gid into next_val from sunshine.gid_seq;

    return next_val;
END;
```

I keep getting an error for the DECLARE:
MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure there should be `**` in line four?

Comment: before the `CREATE`, add this line : `DELIMITER $$`. Replace `END;` by `END$$` followed by this line : `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: The DELIMITER $$ and END$$ followed by DELIMITER ;  worked! Thanks