# ERROR: DELIMITER is not valid at this position, expecting CREATE

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE students.getStudents (IN p_id INT, OUT p_full_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN 
    SELECT students.full_name INTO p_full_name
    FROM students
    WHERE students.id = p_id
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: How are you executing this code? "Delimiter" is a keyword for the client (specifically the MySQL client, and some others that mimic this behaviour).

Comment: https://ibb.co/QXX4jfJ

Comment: Not your immediate error but the select needs a terminator.

Comment: 1) Semicolon after SELECT statement is lost. 2) Does your client software NEEDS in delimiter re-assign really?

Comment: I don't recognize the tool you are using to create the procedure, but it doesn't seem to reuire (or support) a delimiter, but has a special code area for procedures (e.g. it knows it is a procedure). You need to check your manual for what to write there (e.g. you may also not need the `drop` there), and/or tell us which program you are using, so someone can tell you how to use this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need in DELIMITER re-assign and BEGIN-END block because your procedure has one statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE students.getStudents (IN p_id INT, OUT p_full_name VARCHAR(30))
    SELECT students.full_name INTO p_full_name
    FROM students
    WHERE students.id = p_id;
```