# Error in SQL syntax when running SQL in Java but not in HeidiSQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, mariadb, sql-insert

I'm trying to run an *insert* or *update* on a table - the string generated from below works fine when copy pasted into HeidiSQL but throws `SQLSyntaxErrorExceptions` when run from Java:

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
String escapedXML = EscapeString(billboard.getXml());
String sql = String.format(
    "DELIMITER $ \r\nBEGIN NOT ATOMIC\r\n" +
    "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM billboards where Name='%s') THEN UPDATE billboards SET XML='%s' where Name='%s';\r\n" +
    "ELSE insert into billboards(Name, XML, CreatorName) values('%s', '%s', '%s');\r\n" +
    "END IF;\r\n" +
    "END $\r\n" +
    "DELIMITER ;", billboard.getName(), escapedXML, billboard.getName(), billboard.getName(), escapedXML, billboard.getCreatorName());
// Insert or update billboard
statement.execute(sql);
```

I can't figure out why.

Comment: Hi! Knowing the **whole** error it throws would be very helpful in order to try and find out what is happening. Could you please paste it here?

Comment: Sure can:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=113) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER |\r

Comment: @ConnorWilson Why your question has tag `sql-server` but not `MariaDB`?

Comment: Fixed that my bad

Comment: Hi have a look at the error log It usually hints you where the thing goes wrong. Perhaps that `\r` is not a proper delimiter for the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `insert ... ok duplicate key` syntax here rather than a code block. This is more efficient, and implements the lockout a single statement, which should avoid the problem you meet when running the query from your php code.

```
insert into billboards(Name, XML, CreatorName) 
values(?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update set XML = values(XML)
```

For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on column `Name`.

Also, consider using a parameterized  query rather than concatenating variables in your query stringW Escaping is inefficient and does not really make your code safer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried `NamedParameterStatement` with your query to facilitate setting of string parameters and avoid their duplication (using refactored query suggested in [GMB's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62101151/13279831)):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO billboards (Name, XML, CreatorName) VALUES (:name, :xml, :creator) "
             + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET XML = :xml";

NamedParameterStatement statement = new NamedParameterStatement(con, sql);
statement.setString("name", billboard.getName());
statement.setString("xml", EscapeString(billboard.getXml()));
statement.setString("creator", billboard.getCreatorName());

// Insert or update billboard
statement.execute(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting a syntax error is that `DELIMITER` is a MySQL client command and not an SQL statement.  MySQL commands may not be used in with JDBC.

For more information:

- [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)