# Unable to create this MYSQL Trigger on PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to update a column ( called DateModified ) before update happens on the table row.

so here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `date_mod_category` BEFORE UPDATE ON `categories`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.DateModified = NOW();
END
```

**BUT I GET THIS DAMN ERROR WHICH I JUST CANNOT FIGURE OUT WHY:**

[image]

Comment: Since there is only 1 statement in the trigger you don't need BEGIN..END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **DELIMITER**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `date_mod_category` BEFORE UPDATE ON `categories`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   SET new.DateModified = NOW();
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: can you explain why this is required?

Comment: Your welcome @BiswasKhayargoli , please read this answer to find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259528