# My sql order by - Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I am switching from ms sql to my sql , but i am getting a error for a simple order by statement. Cannot figure out whats wrong here .

Error message is "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11"

```
create  PROCEDURE usp_get_orders
(
in p_search_text varchar(255),
out p_exit_status int 
)
BEGIN
    
    
     select * 
     from orders   
     order by order_number desc;


  set p_exit_status = 1;
   
END;
```

Comment: You don't appear to be setting delimiters AND what ide are you using.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a delimiter problem.

In MySQL, you need to define a custom delimiter other than `;` to disambiguate instructions that should be executed in the procedure from instructions to really execute (this is well explained in [this answer for "Delimiters in MySQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/10259528#10259528).

The whole code for your procedure should be something like this:

```
/* Set a custom delimiter other than ; */
DELIMITER $$

create  PROCEDURE usp_get_orders
(
in p_search_text varchar(255),
out p_exit_status int 
)
BEGIN
    
     select * 
     from orders   
     order by order_number desc;


  set p_exit_status = 1;
   
/* Use the custom delimiter to end procedure creation */
END$$

/* Reset the delimiter to the default ; */
DELIMITER ;
```