# Using Delimiter in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Must I use `delimiter` in Mysql to create a procedure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Comment: No.  There are some trivial stored procedures that you can write without a delimiter.  However, it is best to be in the habit of always using a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in a Query tab or in the mysqlclient you need them as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

The problem is a semicolon is the end of a command, but in a stored procedure all semicolons a prt of the stored procedure.

Mysql has to now when he must interpret, the semicolons as part of the procedure by having the DELIMITER changed

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must - unless your procedure is made of a single statement. This is [well explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> Each stored program contains a body that consists of an SQL statement. This statement may be a compound statement made up of several statements separated by semicolon (`;`) characters.
>
> [...]
>
> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the `delimiter` command. [...] This enables the `;` delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

Comment: No, you do not have to. It depends on the client you use.