# Problems with triggers and constraints in mysql with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I keep having error messages and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.
This is the class restaurant:

Restaurant (**IdRestaurant**, NameRest, Telephone, Address, Forks, NameCity, TypeCooking)

The objective is not allow restaurants with Forks that are not in the interval [1,5]

```
CREATE TRIGGER CorrecF
BEFORE INSERT ON Restaurant
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (5 < new.Forks AND new.Forks < 1) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Forks have to be between 1-5';
    END IF;
END;
```

Another one will be not allowing inserts of Offers that have a date less than 2 weeks from NOW().

Offer (**IdOffer**, Coffee, Drink, Date, Price, IdRest, Time_Zone)

```
CREATE TRIGGER CorrectDate BEFORE INSERT ON Offer
 FOR EACH ROW IF (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) > new.Date) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Date have to be minimum 2 weeks from now';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: what error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be setting delimiters see [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql) and your second trigger (like the first) has compound statements see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html so begin..end is required

Comment: I did as you said, but returns me the following error
''ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 88: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)"

I tried in phpmyadmin but as the post of delimiters say, it can't be introduced as usual

Comment: Search for the error message and phpmyadmin set delimiters