# Check the code below to find out the mistake

Tags: mysql

Code in MySQL:

```
create trigger insert_adm
after
  insert on table_student for each row BEGIN
INSERT INTO
  Admission(ID_Student, registration_date)
VALUES
  (new.ID_Student, CURDATE()) END;
```

Error output:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'END' at line 7.

I have no clue what to do
Whats wrong in this mysql code?

Answer (score 0):

Try END$$ instead of END. Some explanation on delimiters here: [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql)

Final code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_adm
AFTER INSERT ON table_student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Admission (ID_Student, registration_date)
    VALUES (new.ID_Student, CURDATE());
END$$
```

Comment: Delimiters and begin..end are not required especially for a single statement in a trigger BUT the single statement does require a terminator.