# Writing a While Loops with Events in MySQL

Tags: mysql, events, while-loop, do-while, mysql-event

I want to write a While Loop with Events in MySQL. After searching the internet, unfortunately, i didn't find something like this. However, i don't want to write it using procedures.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `try` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2023-03-10 09:00:00.000000'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE counter <= 10 DO
    INSERT INTO admin(admin.admin_username, admin.admin_password, admin.admintype_id) VALUES('aaaa','bbbb',1)
    SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE
END;
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Do you get error from this code

Comment: Yes, of course. Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE counter <= 10 DO
    INSERT INTO admin(admin.admin_username, admin.admin_' at line 6

Comment: Try [Delimiters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10259504).

Comment: It's easier to build and test  your code in a procedure than an event, when happy simply copy working code.

Comment: Every day you want to add ten records for the same admin.admin_username, admin.admin_password,? until '2023-03-10 09:00:00.000000' seems to me it would be easier just to do it once for all days.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do something else. This was sample code.
I want to print the data returned from another operation to the other table with events.

Comment: I wrote code like this in procedures:

BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; 
WHILE (i <= 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM kullanici_cocuk 
WHERE SUBSTRING(kullanici_cocuk.cocuk_dogum_tarihi, 6, 5) = SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 6, 5)) 
      ) DO
    INSERT INTO admintouser_cocuk(admintouser_cocuk.kullanici_cocuk_id, admintouser_cocuk.admintouser_cocuk_mesaj)

Comment: VALUES ((SELECT kullanici_cocuk.kullanici_cocuk_id FROM kullanici_cocuk WHERE SUBSTRING(kullanici_cocuk.cocuk_dogum_tarihi, 6, 5) = SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 6, 5)), 'Sevgili evladınızın yeni yaşını kutlar, tüm ailenizle birlikte mutlu bir yaşam dileriz.');
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END

However, since the data returned is more than one, the transaction does not take place.

Comment: insert values with select is just wrong use insert..select and your code is made less readable by all those brackets need more help, add sample data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is an exercise in using a while loop in an event I think the same can be achieved with and insert..select

```
INSERT INTO admintouser_cocuk(admintouser_cocuk.kullanici_cocuk_id, 
            admintouser_cocuk.admintouser_cocuk_mesaj)
SELECT kullanici_cocuk.kullanici_cocuk_id ,
       'Sevgili evladınızın yeni yaşını kutlar, tüm ailenizle birlikte mutlu bir yaşam dileriz.'
FROM kullanici_cocuk 
wHERE SUBSTRING(kullanici_cocuk.cocuk_dogum_tarihi, 6, 5) = SUBSTRING(CURDATE(), 6, 5)
;
```

And I suspect using a date functions rather than subtrings would be tidier too.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much sir.